# Need a script that runs every OSX server restarts

Tags: mac-osx-server, startup-scripts

I need to run a script every time my OSX server (10.5.8) the server restarts.  The closest I could find was to add the script to my login items but this would only apply to one use and I need this script to be run whenever the server restarts to matter which user logs in.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System startup on OS X is managed by launchd.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd, in particular the "External links" section.  Several of these documents describe how to set up launchd services.

Answer (score 0):

larsks is right, launchd is the way to do this.  For a GUI to interact with launchd, check out [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/) -- it works fine on 10.5 and is fairly user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a cronjob that runs at reboot.  Just use the alias @reboot instead of the normal time specification.  See `man 5 crontab` for more info.